# require() of ES Module not supported but the package is based on typescript

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, commonjs

I am using lerna to build independent packages for the project.

The whole structure is shown as

```
root
   -- packages // the folder includes the independent packages 
   -- learn.json
   -- package.json
   -- tsconfig.json
   -- server.ts
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@test1-plugins/got": "file:packages/test1",
 }
```

in which server.ts will help to export all the packages, the code is as

```
import test1 from './packages/test1/index'
...

export default {
  test1,
  .....
}
```

when the main.ts is loading the server.ts

```
import allPlugins from '../root/server.ts';
console.log('allPlugins',allPlugins);
```

The error popped up saying

**Error: require() of ES Module node_modules/_got@13.0.0@got/dist/source/index.js from root/packages/test1/index.ts not supported.**

However the test1 package in the error is coded based on typescript, and **got library is latest version supporting ES6**, why still I am gettng the '**require() of ES Module not supported**'

If you look more closer to the problematic package, it is shown as below.

The test1 's structure is like

-packages
-test
-index.ts
-package.json
-tsconfig.json

```
index.ts 

import got, { Headers } from 'got';
export default class TestQueryService{
   async run(apiKey){
    const response = await got(`https://api.airtable.com/v0/xxxxx`, { method: 'get', headers: this.authHeader(apiKey), });
    return response;
   } 
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "@test-plugins/got",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib",
    "test": "__tests__"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: run tests from root\" && exit 1",
    "build": "tsc -b",
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist && rimraf tsconfig.tsbuildinfo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "got": "^13.0.0",
    "nock": "^13.3.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "type":"module"
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",

    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,

    "strict": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es2015",

    "composite": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "lib"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

update

i change "module" and "moduleResolution" to "module": "esnext", "moduleResolution": "node", but still doesn't work. I also tried "module": "Node16", "moduleResolution": "NodeNext".

but doesn't work still having the require() of ES Module error.

P.S.Each time I remove the old node_modules, and npm i to install the packages again.so far I don't see what goes wrong

Comment: `"module": "commonjs"`, `"moduleResolution": "node"` will cause TS to turn your `import` into `require`. `import got, { Headers } from 'got'` means your project is using an [ESM-only dependency](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/v13.0.0/package.json#L8-L11), so boom you get your error.

Comment: i change "module" and "moduleResolution" to     "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node", but still doesn't work. I also tried     "module": "Node16", "moduleResolution": "NodeNext". but doesn't work still having the require() of ES Module error. Each time I remove the old node_modules, and npm i  to install the packages again.so far I don't see what goes wrong